# AutoComplete interferes with Tab and Enter in the OpenOffice Spreadsheet

Tags: openoffice, spreadsheet

When I have a large data-entry task, I like to uses tab to move to the next cell in a row, and enter to move to the beginning of the next row. When I type into a cell and OpenOffice can autocomplete the information in the cell (from the rows above it in the same column), I can hit enter to accept the current completion and move to the next row, but I can't hit tab to accept the current completion and move to the next cell. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: This question addresses something that has bothered me for years!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to mimic it exactly, but here's a [workaround](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?p=336419#336419)

> Edit the keyboard to allow you to set
>   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> to do the same thing as
>   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Backspace</kbd>.
>
> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Backspace</kbd> navigates to the
>   current cell and allows you to
>   continue to use your <kbd>Tab</kbd> key for right
>   movement, and leaving the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to
>   take you down a row and back to where
>   you started using the Tab key.
>
> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Backspace</kbd> however isn't an easy
>   Keyboard short-cut or at least it
>   isn't for my hands, so I added <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>
>   to do the same thing. A is right next
>   to the Tab key so it's a fairly fast
>   keyboard click.
>
> Tools>Customize>Keyboard> Under
>   Functions In Category, select
>   Navigation Function, select To Current
>   Cell

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is maddening, and should definitely be an option. (Maybe it is, but the options settings are so cluttered I can never find anything.)

Meanwhile, when an autocomplete suggestion appears, just press Delete. You should then be able to press Tab to go to the next cell.

Answer (score 1):

Use the right arrow key instead of tab.

Answer (score 0):

There really is no way to do what you are asking. The software is, in a lot of ways, remarkably inferior to Excel, but it is free.